# Tarring a file with root access

Tags: python, file-permissions, tar

So, I have a directory within a set of directories which has some files & directories owned by root.

Current I am using the below command:

```
tar.add(f)
f = folder_name
```

If let's say folder b has file/files with root privileges, how can I tar it up?

Currently, I get IOError:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ‘file_name'
```

Comment: If you can't read the files with the privileges of the current user you must either run the script as another user or change access rights of the file/folder.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever is creating/copying those files is using root privileges. This is almost certainly a bad idea, so ideally, change that process to use the same credentials as the code you're working on uses.

If that's not possible/feasible, the process that's using root credentials should be able to change the ownership or permissions of those files on download so that your credentials will allow you to work with them.

Answer (score -1):

Run your script as root.

Type `sudo` before your script.

Comment: This is an answer, if a bare bones one. If it wasn't a valid answer, you shouldn't be posting it to get around the reputation threshold for commenting, but in this case, it's fine, it could just use a little more detail (and removing the notes about comments).

Comment: As ShadowRanger says this is a valid answer, your answer explains the reason for the problem and tries to point out a possible solution, comments on changes are used to improve the format of the question or ask for more information.

Comment: "Run it as root" is advice I would avoid until all other possibilities have been exhausted. Also, we don't know if `sudo` is available on the target platform, whether his user has sudo permission, or whether the asker has permission to install/configure sudo.